# How to make NSTimer for multiple different controllers? In swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, nstimer

I make app on page-based.based. I have multiple different controllers. Every controller has `NSTimer` which turn on when the controller `viewDidAppear()`. I made that NSTimer turn off when controller is `viewDidDisappear()`. It works when I slowly slide between controllers but if I fast slide controller some timers don't turn off. I tried several different methods. The first method I post notification to the function which turn off timer but it also works when I slowly slide between controllers. The second method I created public class timer which I used for every controller it doesn't work for me. I don't know how can I make it. Please help me. I also have NSTimer in UIView which is located on UIViewController and I need that when UIViewController is disappear to turn off two timers. How can I make it?

My examples on `ViewController`

```
  var timer: NSTimer!
  override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(true)
        notificationCenter.postNotificationName("turnOnMemoryArc", object: nil)
        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: "showMemory", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    override func viewDidDisappear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidDisappear(true)
        if timer != nil {
            timer.invalidate()
        }
        notificationCenter.postNotificationName("turnOffMemoryArc", object: nil)
    }
```

This code in the view

```
  override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: "turnOnMemoryTimer", name: "turnOnMemoryArc", object: nil)
        notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: "turnOffMemoryTimer", name: "turnOffMemoryArc", object: nil)
//        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: "drawMemoryArc", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

  func turnOnMemoryTimer() {
        print("memory timer is on")
        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: "drawMemoryArc", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    func turnOffMemoryTimer() {
        if timer != nil {
            timer.invalidate()
        }
        print("Memory timer turned")
    }
```

The second method

```
import Foundation

public class GlobalTimer {

    public init() { }
    public var controllerTimer: NSTimer!
    public var viewTimer: NSTimer!

}
```

ViewController

```
 override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(true)
    notificationCenter.postNotificationName("turnOnBatteryArc", object: nil)
    if GlobalTimer().controllerTimer != nil {
        GlobalTimer().controllerTimer.invalidate()
        GlobalTimer().controllerTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: "batteryStateForLabel", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    } else {
        GlobalTimer().controllerTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: "batteryStateForLabel", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
}
```

UIView

```
 func turnOnBatteryTimer() {
        print("turnOnBatteryTimer arc")
        if GlobalTimer().viewTimer != nil {
            GlobalTimer().viewTimer.invalidate()
            GlobalTimer().viewTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: "drawBatteryArc", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        } else {
            GlobalTimer().viewTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: "drawBatteryArc", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem in your code is `GlobalTimer()`. This creates new `GlobalTimer` instance every single time you do write `GlobalTimer()`.

Four **different** instance in the following piece of code - no shared state.

```
if GlobalTimer().viewTimer != nil {
    GlobalTimer().viewTimer.invalidate()
    GlobalTimer().viewTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: "drawBatteryArc", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
} else {
    GlobalTimer().viewTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: "drawBatteryArc", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}
```

You can fix it with singleton pattern ...

```
public class GlobalTimer {
    public static let sharedInstance = GlobalTimer()
    private init() { }
    public var controllerTimer: NSTimer!
    public var viewTimer: NSTimer!
}
```

... by replacing all `GlobalTimer()` occurences ...

```
if GlobalTimer().viewTimer != nil {
```

... with `GlobalTimer.sharedInstace` ...

```
if GlobalTimer.sharedInstance.viewTimer != nil {
```

Next step is `!` removal, which is dangerous and can lead to crash if you don't know what you're doing.

```
public class GlobalTimer {
    public static let sharedInstance = GlobalTimer()
    private init() { }                     <-- avoid instantiation outside the file
    public var controllerTimer: NSTimer?   <-- was !
    public var viewTimer: NSTimer?         <-- was !
}
```

Remaining step is to replace your code using `GlobalTimer` ...

```
if GlobalTimer().viewTimer != nil {
    GlobalTimer().viewTimer.invalidate()
    GlobalTimer().viewTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: "drawBatteryArc", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
} else {
    GlobalTimer().viewTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: "drawBatteryArc", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}
```

... with ...

```
GlobalTimer.sharedInstance.viewTimer?.invalidate()
GlobalTimer.sharedInstance.viewTimer = NSTimer.scheduled...
```

First line says - call `invalidate()` function on `viewTimer` if `viewTimer != nil` otherwise nothing happens (similar to `nil` messaging in ObjC, ...). This allows you to remove the `if` condition, because it invalidates timer or does nothing.

Second line just assigns new timer.

Answer (score -1):

Try putting timer.invalidate() in the view will disappear instead of the did disappear. You shouldn't need the notifications at all when doing this.