# How to stop the timer in other viewcontroller?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode

In my case, my app have three view controller(there are loginview, homeview, menuview)

In the homeview, I set a timer reload data from the server every 10 seconds. Code as shown below:

```
Timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 10, target: self, selector: #selector(loadData), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)


let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "mapFirstPage", bundle: nil)
    let newViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "menuSetupVC") as! menuSetupViewController
    newViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(newViewController, animated: true)
```

And when I go to menuview, there is a logout btn, it can take me to the loginview. But the timer still running in the background...

how can I stop it when I in menuview.

I have solved this problem from this:
[How to make NSTimer for multiple different controllers? In swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34397691/how-to-make-nstimer-for-multiple-different-controllers-in-swift)

Comment: You will need to pass a reference to the view controller or the timer to your other view controllers. Hard to say how to do that exactly in your case since you haven't included any view controller code or specifying how they're connected or how you navigate between them.

Comment: I have updated in the question

Comment: Still not much code to go on... You'd need to add a property in `menuSetupViewController` (by the way, you should capitalize type names in Swift and use lowercase names for variables/properties) that can store a reference to the `Timer`. Then, pass the timer through by doing something like `newViewController.timer = timer` (where `timer` is the `Timer` you've set up)

Comment: @jnpdx sorry i dont know more about that..

Comment: You need to think about your architecture. The timer probably shouldn't be in the view controller. It should be in your model that is, presumably, shared throughout your app.

Answer (score 1):

you can add notification observer to your viewcontroller and notify once you hit on logout action.

Answer (score 0):

```
let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "mapFirstPage", bundle: nil)
    let newViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "menuSetupVC") as! menuSetupViewController
Timer!.invalidate()// will stop the timer
    newViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(newViewController, animated: true)
```

Comment: No, my problem is that the timer only stops when I hit logout, the rest of the time I need it to keep running.

Answer (score 0):

If you just have those three view controllers you can set the Timer like a Singleton, so you can access to them in any part of your code and also you can enable and disable as you need.

So you can use the function .invalidate() to stop it

```
func startTimer() {
    stopTimer()
    guard self.timer == nil else { return }
    self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 10, target: self, selector: #selector(loadData), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

func stopTimer() {
    guard timer != nil else { return }
    timer?.invalidate()
    timer = nil
}
```